# Cannot delete phantom edge in my model

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view, vertices, edges

I'm very new to Blender and I have these phantom vertices/edges in my mesh. The vertices are visible in *Object Mode* and but not in *Edit Mode*, so I cannot manage to select and delete them like I would a normal point. It also does not seem to affect the structure when I'm viewing it with a texture. Could someone explain how it got to be like this and how to get fix it?

[image: phantom edge]

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any modifiers on your object ?

Comment: Yes, it is mirrored on the X axis.

Comment: So this is probably the mirrored part that you see in shadow... if that's it nothing to delete here.

Comment: I've made sure it wasn't just the mirror's shadow. My bottom two pictures relay this best, though it is hard to spot. I'd be nice to take a video and rotate it for everyone, but that seems like a lot of work for what's probably a simple issue.

Comment: Can you share the blend file ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that the vertex is hidden. To hide something, you select it and key <kbd>H</kbd>. This can easily be done by accidentally hitting <kbd>H</kbd> on your way to <kbd>G</kbd> (grab/translate). Hiding is useful for working on one part of your mesh while not having to work around or *Wireframe* through other parts. To un-hide, for lack of a better phrase, key <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.

Once you've un-hidden, key <kbd>X</kbd> and select *Verticies* or perhaps *Edges* in your case.

Comment: This was the issue. Thank you very much! I probably did exactly what you mentioned and hit H instead of G.

Comment: @user25196 Always glad to help. Thank you very much for accepting!

Answer (score 3):

You can select it by pressing <kbd>Z</kbd> first, I'm assuming that you're already in Edit Mode, if not, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to got to Edit Mode, this will allow you to view your object in wireframe, you can select that vertex, then press <kbd>X</kbd> and choose Vertex.
You can also switch to Faces instead of Vertices, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> while in Edit Mode, and choose Faces, each face in the 3D View has a dot in it's center, you can select these faces, then delete them using <kbd>X</kbd> and choosing Faces.

Comment: This will work to delete any other vertex on my mesh, except the one pointed out in my pictures. I've noticed it does not have a small black dot at its tip if that is any indicator.

Comment: It would help if you can upload your .blend file, use this link to upload it, then copy the link to your question: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/